# after ubuntu 19.10 upgrade, Wifi network-manager not working

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I have Dell m3800 with intel wireless 7260.

I upgraded laptop from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 via do-release-upgrade and `network-manager` no longer works. My network card is fine if I boot into Windows or use 19.10 Ubuntu installer.

`network-manager` will connect for a very short while. The systray network icons will switch to "`...`" (never connected) and internet will work (sometimes a minute, sometimes less) and finally a notification that network connection failed and it will go back down.
gnome settings wifi panel will say "Wifi-Unavailable" or "Unavailable 802.1x supplicant failed"

I had to install `wicd` to get stable networking.

## lspci

```
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

## rfkill

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
31 nfc       nfc0   unblocked unblocked
32 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

## syslog

```
Oct 25 00:12:54 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571976774.1063] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct 25 00:12:54 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571976774.1064] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978146.5635] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 5C:51:4F:7C:23:CD
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978146.8569] bluez5: NAP: added interface 5C:51:4F:7C:23:CD
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978148.4205] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978148.4205] device (wlp6s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978148.4214] device (wlp6s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 25 00:35:48 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978148.4232] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 25 00:38:21 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978301.5769] agent-manager: req[0x7f2d5c0019b0, :1.148/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Oct 25 00:40:24 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978424.9081] device (tun0): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Oct 25 00:40:24 mycmpname dbus-daemon[1323]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.15' (uid=0 pid=1336 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 25 00:40:25 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978424.9094] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 25 00:40:36 mycmpname systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.6251] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7201] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7245] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7258] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (9b8049b3-b4dd-4711-9f4f-536729afaeef)
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7261] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7269] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7280] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7284] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname dbus-daemon[1323]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.15' (uid=0 pid=1336 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7823] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7826] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7832] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Oct 25 00:40:50 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1571978450.7844] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Oct 25 00:41:02 mycmpname systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded.
Oct 25 06:43:27 mycmpname NetworkManager[1336]: <info>  [1572000207.3849] agent-manager: req[0x7f2d5c0019b0, :1.148/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
```

## journalctl

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-05-29 21:12:22 EDT, end at Fri 2019-10-25 07:10:26 EDT. --
-- Logs begin at Wed 2019-05-29 21:12:22 EDT, end at Fri 2019-10-25 07:10:26 EDT. --
May 29 21:13:02 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178782.4813] config: unknown key 'wifi.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
May 29 21:13:02 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178782.4813] config: unknown key 'ethernet.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
May 29 21:13:11 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178791.0364] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
May 29 21:13:17 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <error> [1559178797.3588] vpn-connection[0x563b63e560a0,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 29 21:13:17 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178797.3600] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 29 21:13:17 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178797.4052] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 29 21:13:21 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <error> [1559178801.6111] vpn-connection[0x563b63e562b0,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 29 21:13:21 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178801.6125] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 29 21:13:21 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178801.8892] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 29 21:13:26 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <error> [1559178806.1109] vpn-connection[0x563b63e564c0,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 29 21:13:26 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178806.1123] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 29 21:13:26 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178806.3432] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 29 21:13:30 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <error> [1559178810.5733] vpn-connection[0x563b63e566d0,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 29 21:13:30 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178810.5747] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 29 21:13:30 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559178810.7002] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 30 02:29:09 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559197749.8347] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 30 09:13:15 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559221995.6152] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c210,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 30 20:21:47 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559262107.6672] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c2f0,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 04:50:44 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559292644.7199] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c3d0,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 19:08:15 ihatebill NetworkManager[1191]: <warn>  [1559344095.6126] sup-iface[0x563b63d6c4b0,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
-- Reboot --
May 31 19:49:39 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346579.6725] config: unknown key 'wifi.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
May 31 19:49:39 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346579.6725] config: unknown key 'ethernet.cloned-mac-address' in section [device-mac-addr-change-wifi] of file '/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf'
May 31 19:49:50 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346590.3757] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
May 31 19:49:56 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <error> [1559346596.7303] vpn-connection[0x55b0b738a0f0,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 31 19:49:56 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346596.7316] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 31 19:49:56 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346596.8111] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 19:50:00 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <error> [1559346600.9287] vpn-connection[0x55b0b738a300,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 31 19:50:00 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346600.9297] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 31 19:50:01 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346601.3161] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 19:50:05 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <error> [1559346605.4470] vpn-connection[0x55b0b738a510,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 31 19:50:05 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346605.4483] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 31 19:50:05 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346605.6774] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 19:50:09 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <error> [1559346609.8019] vpn-connection[0x55b0b738a720,a6fdcbc5-f6d7-415d-80ff-a19ca8f36bf3,"USA-NEW-YORK.TorGuard",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
May 31 19:50:09 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559346609.8030] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
May 31 21:39:20 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559353160.7134] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270130,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
May 31 22:30:40 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559356240.4985] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270210,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
May 31 22:30:55 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559356255.5346] device (wlp6s0): link timed out.
May 31 22:30:55 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559356255.7070] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MyWifi'
Jun 01 01:14:08 ihatebill NetworkManager[1219]: <warn>  [1559366048.6132] sup-iface[0x55b0b7270210,wlp6s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
```

Comment: Check version of your current Linux kernel with the one in the installer Ubuntu 19.10 installer using `uname -r`. Try to use new version of Linux kernel because according to my experience, most of the driver related problem would get solved this way.

Comment: Upgrading to the latest kernel version did not fix the problem.
wicd is working so kernel/driver likely isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problems with the 19.04 to 19.10 upgrade with a hardwired network card. The solution that I found to at least get the internet working (but not network-manager) is to use the command, 'sudo dhclient enp3s0’ which is for an ethernet card. You might try 'sudo dhclient wlp2s0' which would be for a wifi device. Hope this helps. Since it's been 2 months without an answer, you probably found a different solution.